# Convert Array with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Hello I have a array like this.

```
$myarray = Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Type
        [1] => Brand
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Car
        [1] => Toyota
    )

)
```

I want result like this.

Type = Car

Brand = Toyota

So its mean From First Array "0" Value will be echo then from second array "0" Value will be shown.

Then From First array "1" value will be shown then from second array "1" Value will be shown.

Also I don't know how many array will be comes, So its need to be dynamic.

Any help Please?

Comment: how about `$myarray[0][2]`?  try to understand what are you trying to achieve. Is it **car** and **brand** repeat to pair to the next array value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this (now i have tested it!):

```
foreach($myarray[0] as $titleKey=>$title) {
    echo $title . " = ";
    for($i = 1;$i<count($myarray);$i++) {
        echo $myarray[$i][$titleKey] . ",";
    }
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: Oh so the manual version of [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). Oh, dear PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) for this

```
$myarray = [
  ['Type', 'Brand'],
  ['Car', 'Toyota']
];

list($fields, $values) = $myarray;

$output = array_combine($fields, $values);

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// {
//     "Type": "Car",
//     "Brand": "Toyota"
// }
```

But as you said, it could have more values than just the Toyota, so you'd have to do it like this

```
$myarray = [
  ['Type', 'Brand'],
  ['Car', 'Toyota'],
  ['Horse', 'Seabiscuit']
];

function first ($xs) { return $xs[0]; }
function rest ($xs) { return array_slice($xs, 1); }

$output = array_map(function ($values) use ($myarray) {
  return array_combine(first($myarray), $values);
}, rest($myarray));

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// [
//     {
//         "Type": "Car",
//         "Brand": "Toyota"
//     },
//     {
//         "Type": "Horse",
//         "Brand": "Seabiscuit"
//     }
// ]
```

Note, this final solution assumes that the first array would contain the field names and the remaining arrays would have the values

Of course this works when more fields are added, too. No changes to the code are necessary.

```
$myarray = [
  ['Type', 'Brand', 'Origin'],
  ['Car', 'Toyota', 'Japan'],
  ['Horse', 'Seabiscuit', 'Kentucky']
];

function first ($xs) { return $xs[0]; }
function rest ($xs) { return array_slice($xs, 1); }

$output = array_map(function ($values) use ($myarray) {
  return array_combine(first($myarray), $values);
}, rest($myarray));

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// [
//     {
//         "Type": "Car",
//         "Brand": "Toyota",
//         "Origin": "Japan"
//     },
//     {
//         "Type": "Horse",
//         "Brand": "Seabiscuit",
//         "Origin": "Kentucky"
//     }
// ]
```